# Content Responsive HTML Table

Tags: html, css

I want to display a table inside a container div which allows for scrolling horizontally. I would like the table to be as wide as required, but each column to be be no wider than 60% of the containing div. If the column doesn't need 60%, i.e. not much content, then it should only be as wide as necessary.

I have tried and I can't get it to work, from my searching I don't think this is possible without JavaScript and even then I think it is going to be a MASSIVE pain.

Can someone either tell me I am wasting my time trying, or show e how to get this to work. Here is the code I have tried:
HTML:

```
<div class="process-sitoc-container">
                        <table class="table process-sitoc-table border-bottom table-striped ml-3">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Supplier</th>
                                    <th>Input</th>
                                    <th>Task</th>
                                    <th>Output</th>
                                    <th>Customer</th>
                                    <th>Standard Work</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody class="process-sitoc-table-data">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Text</td>
                                        <td>Text</td>
                                        <td>Long Text</td>
                                        <td>Text</td>
                                        <td>Text</td>
                                        <td>
                                                <a href="/some/link/here" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary table-btn">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-edit table-btn"></i>
                                                </a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Text</td>
                                        <td>Text</td>
                                        <td>Long Text</td>
                                        <td>Text</td>
                                        <td>Text</td>
                                        <td>
                                                <a href="/some/link/here" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary table-btn">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-edit table-btn"></i>
                                                </a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.process-sitoc-container {
    overflow-x: auto;
    width: 100%;
}

.process-sitoc-table {
    display: table;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
}

    .process-sitoc-table th {
        display: table-cell;
        min-width: 20%;
        max-width: 60%;
        overflow-wrap: normal;
    }

.process-sitoc-table-data {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

    .process-sitoc-table-data td {
        display: table-cell;
        min-width: 20%;
        max-width: 60%;
        overflow-wrap: normal;
    }
```

**EDIT:** So I ended up using JavaScript as suggested to me, I also added an extra div between the container and the table. Here is the resulting JavaScript, the getTextWidth function is taken from StackOverflow, maybe this will help someone in the future:

```
function fixSitocTablesWidth(columnCount, maxDivPercentage) {
    var tables = document.getElementsByClassName("process-sitoc-table");

    for (var t = 0; t < tables.length; t++) {
        tables[t].parentNode.style.width = (columnCount * maxDivPercentage) + '%';

        var rows = tables[t].rows;

        var tableContainerViewWidth = tables[t].parentElement.parentElement.clientWidth;
        var maxCellWidth = (tableContainerViewWidth * (maxDivPercentage / 100));

        for (var r = 0; r < rows.length; r++) {
            var cells = rows[r].cells;

            for (var c = 0; c < cells.length; c++) {
                var calWidth = Math.ceil(getTextWidth(cells[c].innerText, window.getComputedStyle(cells[c], null).getPropertyValue('font'))) +
                    parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(cells[c], null).getPropertyValue('padding-left')) + parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(cells[c], null).getPropertyValue('padding-right')) +
                    parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(cells[c], null).getPropertyValue('margin-left')) + parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(cells[c], null).getPropertyValue('margin-right'));
                cells[c].style.width = (calWidth < maxCellWidth) ? calWidth + 'px' : maxCellWidth + 'px';
            }
        }

        tables[t].parentNode.style.width = tables[t].clientWidth + 'px';
    }
}

function getTextWidth(text, font) {
    var canvas = getTextWidth.canvas || (getTextWidth.canvas = document.createElement("canvas"));
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    context.font = font;
    var metrics = context.measureText(text);
    return metrics.width;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't work because there isn't a direct link between the div's width and the column width.

When you set a max-width of 60% on a column, **it means that the column can't exceed 60% of the table's width**, not 60% of the div containing the table.

What you're asking for is what is called in css "container queries", which is a long time requested feature but is still not available.

However, in javascript it can be achieved quite easily. The idea is to store the div's width value (in pixels) and simply apply a max-width value of 60% of the div's width to all th elements (don't need to put this on the td elements if you set it on the headers).

Then, add a resizeobserver on your div to adapt the width of columns as needed.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver

Comment: Thank you, I did think this was the case (the result not the specifics of the detailed explanation you've given), so thank you for putting me out of my misery and explaining exactly why it won't and can't work.

Answer (score 0):

use this css:

```
.table
{
  table-layout: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Hi, this just sets each column to a fixed width of 20% it doesn't react to the size of the content inside the cell.

Comment: This causes the table to only be as wide as the containing div without activating the sideways scrolling, which leaves the content squashed. I did try setting a fixed width of a div between the container and the table, and this works but it means it always shows a sidescroll even of not required.

Comment: I do not know, I usually used pixels myself and set min and max as pixels. Or I created a table in a personal style with div to implement what I want.